# Bouncing a 2D ball off of another 2D object and then make that object disappear in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors, 2d, bounce, collider

[Kinda what the game will look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykVBd.png) I have a 2d ball that is inside of an octagon constructed of 8 different pieces. I set the ball's colour randomly between four different colours and its tag based on those colours. I do the same for the octagon pieces. Basically what I need is to have the ball bounce off of the octagon piece if it's the correct colour/tag, and then set that piece's collider and SpriteRenderer disabled. ***I have tried OnCollisionEnter2D and OnTriggerEnter2D with a 2D physics material and with hard coding the bounce physics, neither work due to the checking of the colour needing to have the octagon's Collider be a trigger, but the bouncing part not working if it's a trigger.*** I know this is probably simple, and I'm just being an idiot xD but I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!

**TL;DR - Ball with the same colour/tag as octagon piece needs to bounce off that piece and set its SpriteRenderer and Collider disabled.**

Comment: Reading is painful, I think it would be helpful if you can draw some pictures or upload a demo project.

Comment: There's a picture for you, hope it helps.

Comment: @BlobKing21 simply use OnCollisionEnter2D and assign a Physics Material 2D to collider component. For Physics Material 2D use Friction value 0 & Bounciness value 1.

Answer (score 0):

[image: A simple demo]
[Simple Demo project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B2rPqZ5uKAytMwEcTJ_sOkil0EZJ4zJZ/view?usp=sharing)

Here I made a simple project based on my understanding of yours, maybe it can help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Thanks @gameDev_Unity, I feel really stupid because I thought you had to get the tag from OnTriggerEnter2D, just tested getting the tag from OnCollisionEnter2D and it works perfectly